# Akka Port Forwarding

Tags: scala, tcp, akka, remoting, portforwarding

I am trying to perform port forwarding towards my Akka program where the client can communicate with the server over the Internet. I have configured my router and the port forwarding mechanism is working but there seems to be a problem with Akka.

The problem is that the client is unable to obtain the remote actor from the server. It keep coming out error at the server side that the recipient are different. The client is obtaining the remote actor through `"akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@67.18.67.18:5150/user/remote"` where `67.18.67.18` is my global IP address for example. Then the remote actor is remoting at the path `"akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@192.168.0.106:5150/user/remote"` where `192.168.0.106` is my local IP of the server. I know that the client must access the remote actor using the same path but despite I defined the `public-localname`, the server still doesn't translate the global IP to the local IP or allow access through the global IP. Is there any workaround to it? Below is the `application.conf` of the server.

```
akka {
   loglevel = "INFO"

   actor {
     provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
   }

   remote {
     enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
     netty.tcp {
       hostname = ""
       port = 5150
       public-hostname = "67.18.67.18"
     }

     log-sent-messages = on
     log-received-messages = on
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config parameter is "bind-hostname" for the interface you want to bind to, and "hostname" for the public IP. You also need to set "bind-port" for the local port to bind to, and "port" for the public IP.

Consult the documentation for more details: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html

Comment: I missed that documentation. I remember I saw that somewhere before. I keep though that public-hostname is the correct mechanism to use. Thanks btw.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to get local address in the conf? I know that hostname = "" will automatically use InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress. But for bind-hostname it doesn't work. I tried bind-hostname = "InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress", also doesn't work. I don't really want to define the address explicitly in the conf. Thank you.

Comment: Provide a default in the config file with an optional system property override and provide the value as a system property on startup: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides

Comment: The method you gave need to provide an environment variable. I actually found a better way where you can use the ConfigFactory to override the properties inside the code. The original post is found below. Nevertheless, I still thank you very much for your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627839/akka-java-programmatic-override-configuration